# How much kernel time is triggered by niced processes?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling

I've got some CPU usage alarms that are triggering when I don't want them to.

I'm reading `/proc/stat`, and comparing the increase in `user` and `system` jiffies to the overall increase of jiffies. If the % increase is high enough then an alarm is raised. Note that I don't count `nice` in this - there are niced processes around, but I'm happy that, if required, these will be descheduled and my important processes will continue on.

However, when the alarm is triggered, I frequently find that the `%user` hasn't gone up at all. However, `%nice` and `%system` do increase - and some of the niced processes would trigger kernel work.

My questions are:

1. Am I right that if the more important processes needed CPU time, the nice'd processes (and the kernel work they trigger) would get descheduled?
2. How can I tell how much of this `%system` is due to niced processes?

Currently running CentOS 6 (2.6.32), but if this is already fixed in later versions I'll consider backporting it!

Answer (score 1):

This probably depends on what the niced process does, in particular how many and what system calls it makes. Here's a not very nice program `notnice.asm` that may show close to worst case behavior as far as system time goes

```
# Linux, x86_64, NASM
bits 64
section .data
letter: db "n"
section .text
global  _start
_start: mov rsi,letter
        mov rdi,1       ; stdout
        mov rdx,1       ; length
_again:                 ; on assumption above not unset by syscall...
        mov rax,1       ; sys_write
        syscall
        jmp _again
```

which even when run under `nice -n 19` should still run the system time up:

```
$ nasm -f elf64 notnice.asm -o notnice.o
$ ld notnice.o -o notnice
$ nice -n 19 ./notnice >/dev/null
```

`top` should then show this process taking up 100% of a CPU as it's in a fairly tight loop, and at least for my otherwise unbusy centos7 test host (that has four CPUs per `/proc/cpuinfo`) something like ~20% system time, ~5% nice, and otherwise idle:

```
%Cpu(s):  0.1 us, 19.1 sy,  5.9 ni, 74.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

In this case ~100% of the system time is due to the not very nice process. With this running, one could also run higher priority processes and then check how the system load changes (and perhaps with SystemTap or something how frequently the `sys_write` from `notnice` happen, or maybe have `notnice` output to a fast filesystem and see if the I/O rates change due to there being higher priority processes about...)

SystemTap may give better granularity for example via https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/general/stopwatches.stp though that requires the process to be in userspace when the recording begins.

Comment: What I need to be able to differentiate is the kernel time triggered between 2 instances of this program - one run under `nice -n 19`, and one not run under nice.

I can tell apart (and ignore!) the userspace time spent - I'd like to do the same for kernelspace time!

Comment: @RobertSworder systemtap may give better insight via `sudo stap -x $pidofyourprocesshere stopwatches.stp` once installed

Comment: I've got one main non-niced process, and lots of niced processes. I don't really care - on a process by process level - which of them is triggering kernel time - just being able to split `%system` is enough for me!

If there's a way, for the whole system, of knowing how much kernel time a process has triggered (on a particular CPU) that would also be enough for me.

ATM I'm considering a kernel patch to add a new `cpustat` (into a fork of `/proc/stat`), but I can't believe I'm the first person to want to know this!